# Does love exist?

Tags: love

The above is a question I would like (love, if you will) an analytic answer to. My belief for the past few years has been, no, definitely not - but I am interested in the counter argument, or if you agree, what causes the illusion of "love" and is it worth pursuing.

Comment: well, it would be conspirational, even, of it to exist mind independently! people experience emotional states (a psychological question).

Comment: See https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/love/

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask. Your question is of a vague and broad kind inviting personal opinions that is not a good fit for this site, we aim at more specific and more or less objectively answerable questions. You'll probably find what you need in philosophy encyclopedia entries like the one Jordan S linked or [IEP's Philosophy of Love](http://www.iep.utm.edu/love).

Comment: Also, please define "love" for the purposes of the question. There are some definitions I can imagine not existing. There are other definitions that clearly exist on a normal basis among closely related animals.

Comment: I agree with the comments above; if you want an analytic answer to this question you need to be more explicit and concrete in what it is that you are asking (define your terms, give more context to what you mean by "love", etc.). Definitely start by reading those articles linked above and then come back and try to reformulate this into a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it depends on the grounds and the context when we say that love does exist - depending on the grounds and the context, I would say that it is possible there is such thing as love that exists in the world, so that when we talk about it, there is something real in the world which corresponds with what we are talking about. However, this question does not necessarily sit within the boundaries of philosophical "argumentation", since the grounds and the context cannot necessarily be stipulated in terms acceptable to philosophical debate. So, even though, the question of love may relate to questions of ontology, any valid answer may necessarily express itself in terms necessarily "unfamiliar" to philosophical debate. For example, for me, I would see love in terms of "telling the truth" and being completely honest with other humans, regardless of what this may "cost" us in the world. This is how I could express what I think of as one of the valid expressions of love - this gives me a marker for when something does not count as love, to me. But the terms in which I express this, are not necessarily reducible to any other terms, since when we try and express what we think of as love, then we come right up against the problem of language, and meaning. So the problem of language, I think, needs to be left *as is*, in order that we can simply express what we think of as love - because insisting on the dubitable nature of "truth", as philosophers could insist on doing, would perhaps minimise what I am trying to say when I express what I think of as love, before even engaging directly in its context, or grounds. In summary, I believe that in order to express what we think of as love, and what it could be, we would need to place on hold certain questions which philosophers may tend to ask, by the nature of philosophy - though the question is related to areas in philosophy, like ontology (the question of "what is"), it is also a question which necessarily stands outside of philosophy - by its own very nature.

Answer (score 0):

Since we can see love and hatred in this world, when you think that love exists, you should think that hatred also exists. (Not only love) Actually this world itself is an illusion (Maya). In some Indian traditions love is not given with great importance. You may have noticed, when love disappears hatred comes up in its place.  So they give importance to 'shanti' (peace) (that transcends both love and hatred).  In Buddhist and Hindu traditions they chant 'shanti' three times.

The reason for chanting ‘peace’ three times is because all obstacles, problems and sorrows originate from three sources:

Aadhidaivika : The unseen divine forces over which we have little or no control like earthquakes, floods, volcanic eruptions etc.

Aadhibhautika: The known factors around us like accidents, human contacts, pollution, crime etc.

Aadhyaatmika : We sincerely pray to the Lord that at least while we undertake special tasks or even in our daily lives.

Please note: Eventually Peace transcends Love.  Then only the word 'liberation' gets the real meaning in all its aspects.